# Delete directory if it ends with a digit in Python

Tags: python, directory, shutil

I'm trying to delete some directories in a path which end with a digit. There are other fodlers in the path that end in letters that I do not want to delete. I am using `shutil.rmtree` because the folders have subfolders that I need to delete too. `file_path` is defined earlier in the script and I know it's pointing to the right location.

```
for folder in file_path :
    if folder.endswith ('/*[0-9]+') :
        shutil.rmtree(folder)
        print("Successfully deleted %s " % folder)
    else:
        print("Error while deleting folder")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if folder.endswith ('/*[0-9]+') :
```

This checks for a folder that ends with exactly that character string: *not* the regular expression you seem to want.  You have to check this specifically.

```
path = folder.split('/')
# Now, check whether the last element is an integer.
file_name = path[-1]
if file_nam.isdigit(e):
    ...
```

In a single line ...

```
if folder.split('/')[-1].isdigit():
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this and it works:

```
files = os.listdir(file_path)
for file in files:
    if re.match('.*\d', file):
        shutil.rmtree(file)
        print("Successfully deleted %s " % file)
```